# Read floats from file with different precision in C

Tags: c, file

If I have a file that contains lines with float numbers like this:

```
4.5 -3.2 3.3 5.62 0.56 3.231
5.632 -4.56 2 5.8212 4 6.7
```

How can I read it line by line and splitting the numbers to save them in an array (they are separated by 1 tabulator).

Thank you

EDIT:

I did the following and it works, thanks everyone for helping

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    float array[2][6];
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(j=0;j<6;j++){
            fscanf(f,"%f",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(j=0;j<6;j++){
            printf("%f ", array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you rely on each line to have exactly six numbers, as in the example?

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read each line, `strtok()` to split it at whitespace, and `atof()` to convert each string to floating point.

Comment: Do you mean to store all the numbers from all the lines in the one long 1D array?  Or do you mean to fill a 2D array?  Or maybe with each line you overwrite the values from the previous line?

Comment: Yes @JohnBollinger every line will have the same amount of numbers

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I'll take a look to that

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'd like to save them in a 2D vector. In this example it would be like content[2][6], so the first row would be filled with the 6 numbers from the first line and the second row with the 6 numbers from the second line.

Comment: the 'with different precision' phrase in the question suggests that there is more to this question

Comment: You should post your own answer as an _answer_, not a continuation of the question.  Your answer has weaknesses.

Comment: In your answer, it would be more reliable (better accuracy) to use type `double` instead of `float`.  You should also check the return values from `fscanf` to detect parsing errors or invalid input files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.  If you can rely on the input to be formatted as you describe, then `scanf()` is probably the easiest way to do the job.  The fact that the details of each number's formatting varies is no obstacle.  For example:

```
float array[2][6];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
    int result = scanf("%f%f%f%f%f%f", &array[i][0], &array[i][1], &array[i][2],
            &array[i][3], &array[i][4], &array[i][5]);

    if (result < 6) {
        /* handle error or EOF or malformed input */
    }
}
```

`scanf()` automatically ignores leading whitespace, including line breaks, before most field types and breaks fields of most types at whitespace.  It returns the number of fields successfully scanned and assigned, or `EOF` if 
an error occurs or if the end of the file is reached before any field is successfully matched.

Answer (score 1):

Uses [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) go get a line of your file in a string. Than use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) to parse the float into variables.